# Is there any efficient easy way to compare two lists with the same length with Mathematica?

Tags: arrays, list, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Given two lists `A={a1,a2,a3,...an}` and `B={b1,b2,b3,...bn}`, I would say `A>=B` if and only if all `ai>=bi`.

There is a built-in logical comparison of two lists, `A==B`, but no `A>B`. 
Do we need to compare each element like this

`And@@Table[A[[i]]>=B[[i]],{i,n}]`

Any better tricks to do this?

**EDIT:**
Great thanks for all of you.

Here's a further question:

How to find the Maximum list (if exist) among N lists?

[Any efficient easy way to find the maximum list among N lists with the same length using Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889583/any-efficient-easy-way-to-find-the-maximum-list-among-n-lists-with-the-same-leng)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Method 1**: I prefer this method.

```
NonNegative[Min[a - b]]
```

**Method 2**: This is just for fun. As Leonid noted, it is given a bit of an unfair advantage for the data I used. 
If one makes pairwise comparisons, and return False and Break when appropriate,
then a loop may be more efficient (although I generally shun loops in mma):

```
result = True;
n = 1; While[n < 1001, If[a[[n]] < b[[n]], result = False; Break[]]; n++]; result
```

---

**Some timing comparisons on lists of 10^6 numbers:**

```
a = Table[RandomInteger[100], {10^6}];
b = Table[RandomInteger[100], {10^6}];

(* OP's method *)
And @@ Table[a[[i]] >= b[[i]], {i, 10^6}] // Timing

(* acl's uncompiled method *)
And @@ Thread[a >= b] // Timing

(* Leonid's method *)
lessEqual[a, b] // Timing

(* David's method #1 *)
NonNegative[Min[a - b]] // Timing
```

[image: timings 2]

---

Edit: I removed the timings for my Method #2, as they can be misleading. And Method #1 is more suitable as a general approach.

Comment: Note that since you generate random lists, your last method (in which there are strange hard-coded constants, but I assume those are remnants from your development code. Anyways, they are making it wrong here, but let's ignore that for a moment) gets an unfair advantage, since statistically the condition violation will happen very early in the loop. You should also test for the lists where the result would be `True` - in which case top-level lists are guaranteed to be slower. In fact, your last method is a top-level variation of the compiled code of @acl.

Comment: This of course does not detract from your beautiful and fast first method, which I admire.

Comment: Well, the last one is much faster because it short-circuits, breaking as soon as any two elements don't match. Try it in the worst case (ie, when they must all be compare, eg `a=b`), and it's by far the slowest. The fastest is the compiled method `cmp`, I think.

Comment: By the way, in many cases, a compiled (to C) loop is more efficient than anything else you could do. Uncompiled top-level loops tend to be the slowest overall (unless you are using a much more efficient algorithm, as you are here).

Comment: @Leonid. I also prefer Method #1.  Method #2 was to examine the speed advantage of Th breaking early out of the loop. You are quite correct about the list generation: If numbers are randomly assigned to a, b, then Method #2 gets an unfair advantage.

Comment: @acl We do need collaborative comments (like in piratePad), don't we :) ?

Comment: @acl I don't know how to run your compiled code but would gladly include it in the comparison if you tell me how. Do I need to have C installed on my machine?

Comment: @David It didn't occur to me that a C compiler may not be available on some systems. If you don't have one, you may replace `"C"` with `"WVM"`. This, though, is 30 times slower here. When I run all the examples, the compile to C one is by far the fastest, as expected (I'm talking about worst-case scenarios).

Comment: @acl Yes, compiled C is very fast.

Comment: Very cool! Great Thanks for all of you. This is a wonderful day.

Answer (score 8):

For instance,

```
And @@ Thread[A >= B]
```

should do the job.

EDIT: On the other hand, this

```
cmp = Compile[
  {
   {a, _Integer, 1},
   {b, _Integer, 1}
   },
  Module[
   {flag = True},
   Do[
    If[Not[a[[p]] >= b[[p]]], flag = False; Break[]],
    {p, 1, Length@a}];
   flag],
  CompilationTarget \[Rule] "C"
  ]
```

is 20 times faster. 20 times uglier, too, though.

EDIT 2: Since David does not have a C compiler available, here are all the timing results, with two differences. Firstly, his second method has been fixed to compare all elements. Secondly, I compare `a` to itself, which is the worst case (otherwise, my second method above will only have to compare elements up to the first to violate the condition).

```
(*OP's method*)
And @@ Table[a[[i]] >= b[[i]], {i, 10^6}] // Timing

(*acl's uncompiled method*)
And @@ Thread[a >= b] // Timing

(*Leonid's method*)
lessEqual[a, b] // Timing

(*David's method #1*)
NonNegative[Min[a - b]] // Timing

(*David's method #2*)
Timing[result = True;
 n = 1; While[n < Length[a], 
  If[a[[n]] < b[[n]], result = False; Break[]];
  n++]; result]

(*acl's compiled method*)
cmp[a, a] // Timing
```

[image]

So the compiled method is much faster (note that David's second method and the compiled method here are the same algorithm, and the only difference is overhead).

All these are on battery power so there may be some random fluctuations, but I think they are representative.

EDIT 3: If, as ruebenko suggested in a comment, I replace `Part` with `` Compile`GetElement ``, like this

```
cmp2 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Module[{flag = True}, 
   Do[If[Not[Compile`GetElement[a, p] >= Compile`GetElement[b, p]], 
     flag = False; Break[]], {p, 1, Length@a}];
   flag], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

then `cmp2` is a twice as fast as `cmp`.

Comment: +1. You could probably make this a bit simpler: `cmp1 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}},  Do[If[a[[p]] < b[[p]], Return[False]], {p, 1, Length@a}] != False,   CompilationTarget -> "C"]`.

Comment: Compilation is clearly faster. I'm surprised, nonetheless, that my method #1 did as well as it did.

Comment: @David perhaps it is so fast because `Developer`PackedArrayQ[a - b]` returns `True`

Comment: For fun, try Compile`GetElement[a,p] instead of Part[a,p] and the second one.

Comment: My method #2 is definitely not the way to go for large lists when the result is True.

Comment: @David except if compiled, when it's the fastest (it's the same as `cmp` above). Especially with ruebenko's undocumented trick!

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned efficiency as a factor in your question, you may find these functions useful:

```
ClearAll[lessEqual, greaterEqual];
lessEqual[lst1_, lst2_] :=
   SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[lst2 - lst1]]["NonzeroPositions"] === {};

greaterEqual[lst1_, lst2_] :=
   SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[lst1 - lst2]]["NonzeroPositions"] === {};
```

These functions will be reasonably efficient. The solution of @David is still two-four times faster, and if you want extreme speed and your lists are numerical (made of Integer or Real numbers), you should probably use compilation to C (the solution of @acl and similarly for other operators).

You can use the same techniques (using `Unitize` instead of `UnitStep` to implement `equal` and `unequal`), to implement other comparison operators (`>`, `<`, `==`, `!=`). Keep in mind that `UnitStep[0]==1`.

Comment: Your functions are more than 4 times slower than mine, according to my timing results.

Comment: @David I think that depends on the data. In my tests, I had 2 times difference. But yes, they are slower (than your first function at least). I will still keep this answer though, since it illustrates how `SparseArray`-s can be used, but I agree that your solution is superior.

Comment: I mentioned the timing ratio based on Method #1 (since Method #2 is really just for fun).

Comment: @David I also meant method#1. I have: `largeTst1 = RandomInteger[1000, 10000000];largeTst2 = RandomInteger[{999, 1990}, 10000000];In[95]:= NonNegative[Min[largeTst2-largeTst1]]//Timing Out[95]= {0.125,False}; In[96]:= greaterEqual[largeTst2,largeTst1]//Timing Out[96]= {0.234,False}`.

Answer (score 3):

Comparison functions like `Greater, GreaterEqual, Equal, Less, LessEqual` can be made to apply to lists in a number of ways (they are all variations of the approach in your question).

With two lists:

```
 a={a1,a2,a3};
 b={b1,b2,b3};
```

and two instances with numeric entries

```
na={2,3,4}; nb={1,3,2};
```

you can use

```
And@@NonNegative[na-nb]
```

With lists with symoblic entries

```
And@@NonNegative[na-nb]
```

gives

```
NonNegative[a1 - b1] && NonNegative[a2 - b2] && NonNegative[a3 - b3]
```

For general comparisons, one can create a general comparison function like

```
listCompare[comp_ (_Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Equal | _Less | _LessEqual), 
         list1_List, list2_List] := And @@ MapThread[comp, {list1, list2}]
```

Using as

```
listCompare[GreaterEqual,na,nb]
```

gives `True`. With symbolic entries

```
listCompare[GreaterEqual,a,b]
```

gives the logially equivalent expression `a1 <= b1 && a2 <= b2 && a3 <= b3`.

Answer (score 2):

When working with packed arrays and numeric comparator such as `>=` it would be hard to beat David's Method #1.

However, for more complicated tests that cannot be converted to simple arithmetic another method is required.

A good general method, especially for unpacked lists, is to use `Inner`:

```
Inner[test, a, b, And]
```

This does not make all of the comparisons ahead of time and can therefore be much more efficient in some cases than e.g. `And @@ MapThread[test, {a, b}]`.  This illustrates the difference:

```
test = (Print[#, " >= ", #2]; # >= #2) &;

{a, b} = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 3, 4, 5}};

Inner[test, a, b, And]
```

> ```
> 1 >= 1
> 2 >= 3
>
> False
> ```

```
And @@ MapThread[test, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> 1 >= 1
> 2 >= 3
> 3 >= 3
> 4 >= 4
> 5 >= 5
>
> False
> ```

If the arrays are packed and especially if the likelihood that the return is `False` is high then a loop such as David's Method #2 is a good option.  It may be better written:

```
Null === Do[If[a[[i]] ~test~ b[[i]], , Return@False], {i, Length@a}]
```

> ```
> 1 >= 1
> 2 >= 3
>
> False
> ```

Comment: Actually it's not hard at all, there's a method in my answer that is roughly an order of magnitude faster... (good tip on `Inner`, I did not know about the efficiency advantage, +1)

Comment: @acl I don't count compiling to C. ;-) (I know I should probably get over it, but between not having it in v7 and the need to write in that awful procedural style I am just not ready to accept that as *Mathematica*.)   Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Why do you say "If the arrays are packed..." then a loop is a good choice? If I unpack `a` and set `b=a`, the unpacked-list version is a little bit slower than the packed one. ie, packing doesn't really affect `Do` and company's performance (although they do not seem to unpack). Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @acl I meant that there is a significant unpacking overhead when using `Inner` even if the very first pair does not pass `test`.  Using `Part` in `Do` avoids this.  If you understand what I mean, and can think of a better way to state it, please do.