# Any efficient easy way to find the maximum list among N lists with the same length using Mathematica?

Tags: arrays, list, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

This question is a continuation of a previous thread to compare two lists with the same length:

[Is there any efficient easy way to compare two lists with the same length with Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885505/is-there-any-efficient-easy-way-to-compare-two-lists-with-the-same-length-with-m)

Given two lists `A={a1,a2,a3,...an}` and `B={b1,b2,b3,...bn}`, I would say `A>=B` if and only if all `ai>=bi`. Now we have `k` lists `H={{a11,a12,a13,...a1n}, {a21,a22,a23,...a2n},...,{ak1,ak2,ak3,...akn}}`, and want to find the maximum one if exist.

Here's my code:

`Do[If[NonNegative[Min[H[[i]] - h]], h = H[[i]], ## &[]], {i, h = H[[1]]; 1, Length[H]}];h`

Any better trick to do this?

EDIT:

I want to define this as a function like:

`maxList[H_]:=Do[If[NonNegative[Min[H[[i]] - h]], h = H[[i]], ## &[]], {i, h = H[[1]]; 1, Length[H]}];h`

But the question is the code above cross two lines, any fix for this? Here is some code working but not that beautiful

`maxList[H_] := Module[{h = H[[1]]}, Do[If[NonNegative[Min[H[[i]] - h]], h = H[[i]], ## &[]], {i, Length[H]}]; h]`

or

`maxList[H_]:=Last[Table[If[NonNegative[Min[H[[i]] - h]], h = H[[i]], ## &[]], {i, h = H[[1]]; 1, Length[H]}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modification of Mr.Wizard's approach works a few times faster.

```
maxListFast[list_List] := Module[{l}, 
                                 l = Max /@ Transpose@list; 
                                 If[MemberQ[list, l], l, {}]]
```

We test the both methods with

```
test  = RandomInteger[100, {500000, 10}];
test1 = Insert[test, Table[100, {10}], RandomInteger[{1, 500000}]];
```

and we get

```
In[5]:= maxList[test] // Timing
        maxListFast[test] // Timing

        Out[5]= {2.761, {}}
        Out[6]= {0.265, {}}
```

and

```
In[7]:= maxList[test1] // Timing
        maxListFast[test1] // Timing

Out[7]= {1.217, {{100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}}}
Out[8]= {0.14, {100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}}
```

**EDIT**

In general,  to choose a method, we should know first what kind of data we are to deal with. (lenght of lists, their number, types of numbers ).  While we have a large number of short lists
 of integers `maxListFast` works even 10 times better (in case of 500000 lists of length 10)  than `maxList`. 
However for lists of real numbers it is only 3-4 times faster, and the more and the longer list we have the more it slows down, e.g. :

```
         A = RandomReal[1000, {3000, 3000}];
         First@AbsoluteTiming[maxListFast@A;]/ First@AbsoluteTiming[maxList@A;]

Out[19]= 2.040516
```

however if we insert "the greatest element" :

```
In[21]:= IA = Insert[A, Table[1000, {3000}], RandomInteger[{1, 3000}]];
In[22]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[maxListFast@IA;]/ First@AbsoluteTiming[maxList@IA;]

Out[22]= 0.9781931
```

timings close up.

Comment: I did not check the cost of `Intersection`.  Good catch.

Comment: The cost of `Intersection` vs. `MemberQ` depends on the dimensions of the data. If you compare `maxList` and `maxListFast` on the data `Transpose[test]` the timing ranks can be reversed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for upvote,  I've been to add  a neat method without module, but You had done it first. Although both methods seem to be very similar with respect to performance.

Comment: Artes, congratulations on the accepted answer.  Please consider updating your code to the Module-free version you came up with, or mine if you prefer it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thank you.  In fact, the `Module`-free version is a bit more elegant. However a comprehensive updating to describe case -specific aspects of the question needs quite a long time, which I miss at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that this should work:

```
maxList = # \[Intersection] {Max /@ Transpose@#} &;

maxList[ {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 3}, {4, 3, 5}, {5, 6, 7}} ]
```

> ```
> {{5, 6, 7}}
> ```

---

I did not think about the cost of using `Intersection`, and Artes shows that `MemberQ` is a much better choice. (Please vote for his answer as I did).  I would write the function without using `Module` myself:

```
maxList[a_] := If[MemberQ[a, #], #, {}] &[Max /@ Transpose@a]
```

A nearly equivalent though not *quite* as fast method is this:

```
maxList = Cases[#, Max /@ Transpose@# , 1, 1] &;
```

The result is in the form `{{a, b, c}}` or `{}` rather than `{a, b, c}` or `{}`.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `Max /@` instead of `Last /@ Sort /@`.

Comment: @celtschk Indeed; as with Osiris' previous question I was considering generalization, though I did not state this, and I also did not show how a custom comparator would be used.  It would be more efficient to use `Ordering` and `Part` for the generalized form as kguler did.  I shall rethink the value of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Some Data:** Btw, it's not actually necessary to label the individual sublists. I did so for easy reference.

```
a = {4, 5, 6}; b = {1, 4, 3}; c = {4, 3, 5}; d = {5, 6, 7};

lists = {a, b, c, d};
```

---

**maxList** determines whether a sublist is a greatest list, i.e. whether each of its elements is greater than the respective elements in all other sublists. We initially assume that a sublist is a maximal list. If that assumption is violated (note the use of `Negative` rather than `NonNegative`) False is returned. BTW, a list will be compared to itself; that's easier than removing it from `lists`; and it doesn't affect the result.

```
maxList[list_] :=
   Module[{result = True, n = 1},
   While[n < Length[lists] + 1, 
   If[Negative[Min[list - lists[[n]]]], result = False; Break[]];  n++]; result]
```

---

Now let's check whether one of the above sublists is a maxList:

```
greatestList = {};
n = 1; While[n < Length[lists] + 1, 
If[maxList[lists[[n]]], greatestList = lists[[n]]; Break[]]; n++];
Print["The greatest list (if one exists): ", greatestList]

(* output *)
The greatest list (if one exists): {5,6,7}
```

Sublist d is a maxList.

If there were no maxList, the result would have been the empty list.